# Difference between htons and htonl

Tags: sockets, unix, networking

I was learning about simple socket programs and had come across these,
I wanted to know what is the difference between htons and htonl, even ntohs and
ntohl.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**htons** host to network short 
**ntohs** network to host short 
**htonl** host to network long 
**ntohl** network to host long

long is 32 bits. short is 16 bits.

Comment: Is host big-endian? Or in network? This doesn't help me understand what's happening

Comment: Is `htons()` always used for the _port_ number? Or, do we ever use `htonl()` for the port?

Comment: @Ky The TCP/IP standard network byte order is big-endian. Host depends: linux is little endian but some host can be big endian and then it is identity function