# Decide between htons and htonl

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I have read [this explanation](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/htonsman.html) and [this manual page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/htonl.html) about the usage of `htons`, `htonl`, `ntohl` and `ntohs`, however I still do not fully understand their usage (I am quite new to the socket API and network programming in general). I do understand little and big Endian and byte order, but I'm not sure how to correctly implement these functions in my chat application code so it works consistently across different machines (where one uses big Endian and another uses little).

A little context to my specific situation; I have an (almost) fully working chat application, and have just been using `htons`, but after some research it seems this is unreliable. I realise that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33985763/3016335) might seem quite similar, however here I am asking about an implementation example, I already am aware of the basic function of these calls.

Comment: *"but after some research it seems this is unreliable"* Not sure what you mean by that. Please explain.

Comment: I don't mean the function is unreliable, I mean that if I don't use the correct function then my program could be sending unexpected data (wrong byte order). Please correct me if I'm wrong but on the first link I provided, it said this: *"The upshot of this is that if you send() a two-byte short int from an Intel box to a Mac (before they became Intel boxes, too, I mean), what one computer thinks is the number 1, the other will think is the number 256, and vice-versa.*"

Comment: When you are about to *send* data from your host over the network, you prepare it using hton*. When you receive data fir your host from the network, you use ntoh*. You choose the `s` version if the data is in a `short` (or, more accurately, an `int16_t`) and the `l` variant if it is a `long`.  What about that is confusing?

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Stupid question, but should I use this for all transfers (e.g. when I'm sending any data), because at the moment the only instance in which I'm using htons is to place the port number (5000) into my sockaddr_in struct's sin_port int?

Comment: @carefulnow: you should use these for all data where byte order is relevant. This means 16bit and 32bit numbers (i.e. htons, htonl) but not char or char[] since you cannot change the byte order if you have only one byte. What kind of data types your application uses inside the transferred data you hopefully know yourself.

Comment: So do I not need to use hton* when storing the port number in server_sin.port? (I am only doing this because an example said so.) Also I'm only sending character arrays so I will never have to use hton*, correct?

Comment: You *do* need `htons` for the port number, and `htonl` for the IP address (assuming IPv4 address in a 32-bit variable). As for the data, it all depends on how you format it.

Comment: Oh well the data is just a char array, I don't need to use hton* for that right?

Comment: Not very important but for completeness, the latest POSIX specification ("Issue 7") on the functions in question are here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/htonl.html

Comment: If the data is strictly a char array, then you are correct that you don't need hton* for that. But if, for example, the data is preceded by a 16-bit length, then you would need to use `htons` on the length field.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the help. One question though; why do I need to use hton* on the IP and port? All I'm doing is getting a value from the user and putting it in a struct (sockaddr_in).

Comment: Yup, but whatever you put into that `struct` gets sent byte-by-byte over the wire, so the bytes need to be in network order.

Comment: So if I have a struct, declared like this: `sockaddr_in server;` and then do `inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &server.sin_addr.s_addr);` to assign the IP, then `server.sin_port = 5000` to assign the port, would I want to change the IP parameter in `inet_pton` to `htonl("127.0.0.1")`, and the port setup to `htons(5000)`? If so, why is that struct been sent over the network at all? Isn't it just for the client's use to know the server details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is have some common representation for integer types. TCP/IP uses NBO, the Network Byte Ordering. And whatever it is (big or little endian or more exotic) the way to send a 16 bits integer, or a 32 bits is to use `htons` or `htonl` before sending such a data. Then when receiving you have to convert it back to your host representation with `ntohs` and `ntohl`:

Sender want to send value `uint32_t a`, then it sends data returned by `htonl(a)`, say d.

Receiver gets `d`, applies `ntohl(d)` and get a correct `uint32_t` value.

Theses are just *coding/decoding* functions. Sender sends code(v), then receiver gets decode(code(v))! You don't have to know what code(v) equals to (no interest).

If it seems unreliable to you, this is because you don't use it as it should be.

Comment: I do understand this part, but why are some users saying I should use it when storing the port number in my server struct? As far as I can see it's not been sent anywhere, the only thing that's been sent is the char array containing the message...

Comment: What you called *server struct*? Remember that when sending message there is a lot of information that package your data, sender ip infos, receiver ip infos, etc. So there is a need to give them in precise byte ordering.

Comment: Ah, so when the client executes write(sock, message, strlen(message)), that is also sending some data such as server.sin_port?

Comment: Of course, if not how your data could have been routed correctly to the destination? Read about the way IP-stack works.

Comment: Haha, I didn't think it through (read my description, you'll realise why). Anyway thanks for the help.

Comment: I understand ;-) but age makes no difference; yours is just a good hint that your are new in the field (then follow my advice: read, read, ask, read, read, ask...).

Comment: Alright, thanks for the advice. So if I set up the byte order correctly and everything, where do I need to decode it using ntohl and ntohs on the server end?

Comment: Each time you get something from the *network* you'll have to decode it network to host noth.

Comment: Ye but where? The only part where I'm getting any data from the client is when the server calls recv in another thread. Consider this: readSize = recv(sockfd, clientMsg, MSG_SZ, 0). If clientMsg had been sent over the socket after been encoded with hton*, would I only need to do a ntoh* on clientMsg?

Comment: exactly, if you send something that has been encode with hton then you need to decode it with ntoh, nothing more (or less).

Comment: Is it best practice to always decode everything I recieve (even if I never use it)?